# About basic commands in bash (cp, cd,..)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to learn basic commands in the terminal. I have a couple of quick questions. I know that to make a file and place it in a specific folder, one needs to create the directory and then use `touch` to create an empty file and place it there by `mv`:

```
mkdir folder/sub

touch file.txt

mv file.txt folder/sub
```

Could we somehow chain these things together and use `touch` to create a file and place it in a specific directory in just one line?

and then if I am in a sub-directory, in order to get back from there (say: folder/sub) to my home, either of these three commands would work (`cd`, `cd -`, `cd ..`) I am not sure I get the differences among the three. I get that `cd ..` takes you back one step up but the other two seem to work exactly the same.

and let's say I have already a text file in my home directory named `file.txt`. If I write this in shell it overrides that existing file:

`cp folder/sub/file.txt ~/`

How would I go about this if I wanted to keep both files?

Comment: `mkdir folder/sub;touch file.txt;mv file.txt folder/sub`

Comment: You just rearranged the code in one line. That's not what I meant.

Comment: then create a file in a particular directory itself by `touch /foo/bar/file.txt`

Comment: A side effect of `touch` is that the target file is created if it doesn't already exist, but `touch` is not necessary. You can simply use a shell output redirection as well, which does not require an external command to be run: `> folder/sub/file.txt`.

Comment: @jm666 Why so angry? No need to go for the jugular. I haven't used other parts of StackOverflow much but you are right, I should've used another section. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can pass a relative or absolute path in any folder to and command, including `touch` (although the folder must exist):

  ```
  touch folder/sub.file.txt
  ```
- `cd -` switches to the folder you were last in (like a "Back" button)
- `.` means the current directory
- `..` means the parent directory

Comment: Thanks, how about the `cp` command where the files are overridden? How would I rewrite it if I need to keep them both?

Comment: Use `cp -i` (here 'i' stands for interactive). The best practice is just to make an alias in .bashrc, .zshrc or whatever shell you are using: `alias cp='cp -iv'`.